# Tkinter transparentcolor working with .py but not with .pyw

Tags: python, tkinter, pythonw

`root.attributes("-transparentcolor", "white")` won't work with a `.pyw` file extension

Up until yesterday all my tkinter GUIs have been working like they should but two days ago all of them stopped working like I want them to. The line `root.attributes("-transparentcolor", "white")` has always made the white color transparent, like it should, but now it doesn't work like it used to. It does work properly if I launch the program with a `.py` file extension but not with a `.pyw`. Obviously I don't want a console window to open along with all of my programs so this is not something I could just accept. Like I said, this has worked fine up until yesterday.

For the past day I've been doing all kinds of things to try to fix this, I even uninstalled python completely and reinstalled the latest version, but nothing has changed my problem.

I'm on `Windows 10 and python 3.9.1` right now (after the reinstall, can't remember what version I had before)

I didn't do a single thing that could've made this happen, I didn't update or change anything before my problem showed up, I simply started my computer in the morning like always.

Does anyone have any clue on what I could try? Could anyone try to do the same thing and see if it works for you?

Code below creates a tkinter window with a transparent background if saved as a .py file, but creates a tkinter window with white background if saved like a .pyw file.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.config(bg= 'white')
root.attributes('-transparentcolor', 'white')

root.mainloop()
```

Update:
Hmm... I've discovered something interesting!
If I start my program through cmd prompt with pythonw my problem still appears, but if I do the same thing with a cmd prompt running as administrator it all works like before, I get a transparent background!

Update 2:
I've set pythonw.exe to always run as administrator, and this solves my problem. But if I do that I always get a uac prompt which I never got before, so I haven't fixed my problem, I've just found a tedious workaround.

Comment: It works fine in my Windows 10 running Python 3.9.1 for both .py and .pyw.

Comment: @acw1668 thanks for trying! Good to know that it's a problem on my end and not a general problem for windows or python.

Comment: Can't you disable the UAC prompt for `pythonw.exe` somehow?

Comment: Pretty sure I can, but for security reasons id rather not. It would be very easy for me to accidentally copy the wrong piece of code and f up my pc.  Also, I didn't have to do it this way before and I really want to figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Allrighty then... I've found a solution, even though I do not like it. I don't have anything against windows or Microsoft, but I really do not like the Microsoft store. But I have to give in, this does solve my problem:

I went and installed python 3.9 from the Microsoft store. I do not know why I did it. I do not know why it helped. I started my .pyw file with the installed program/app called "Python 3.9 (Windowed)" and badaboom, badabing, my problem for some frickin reason, disappeared...

I don't know if this is a viable solution long term (or at all for that matter) but it solves my problem, and after 2 days of continuously smashing my head against the keyboard and wanting to set my pc on fire, I have to accept this as a solution and move on...

Thank u @acw1668 and @martineau for trying to help, I really appreciate it!

Tl;dr:

Download python from Microsoft store and use that program to start the file